# When does FireFox ask for confirmation on page redirect?

Tags: web-development, forms, firefox, post

Every once in a while I click a link and see the following (I'm using FF 11.0):

[image]

I was wondering why FF does this on some redirects/links and not on others. I was thinking maybe it does that when you're on a page that contains a `<form>` element?

Thanks for any help here/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with JavaScript, using the `window.onbeforeunload` event ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Some browsers will even let you specify (part of) the text in the dialog box by returning a string from the event handler, but [for security reasons](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292), recent versions of Firefox (which you appear to be using) will ignore the string and just always present the same fixed message.

Here's some example code from the MDN page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```